# Inserting a python time object to a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a MySQL database. I use python `mysqldb` module to access this database. I have a table which has a column with mysql data type `time`.

Which python data type should I use to insert a time value into this column? What should I be using in the execute statement?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can use `datetime.time`, `datetime.datetime`  or a string for the data type.

Assuming you've already set up a cursor, then it's a pretty simple query if you're just adding times to the table.

```
cursor.execute('''insert into table my_table (time_column) values (%s)''', '2022-12-25 10:32:23')
cursor.execute('''insert into table my_table (time_column) values (%s)''', '10:32:23')
cursor.execute('''insert into table my_table (time_column) values (%s)''', datetime.time(10,32,23)
cursor.execute('''insert into table my_table (time_column) values (%s)''', datetime.datetime(2022,12,25,10,32,23)))
```

Will all result in a time of `10:32:23` being added to the MySQL table `my_table` in the column labelled `time_column`.